# DNS doctoring between 3 interfaces

Tags: cisco-asa

I have a guest network with a range of 192.168.13.x on m y192.168.13.1 interace.  I need it to get to my external webpage at 1.2.3.4 on my outside interface.  The webserver itself sits in the DMZ at 10.10.10.x on the 10.10.10.1 interface.  For the life of me I can't figure out where to put the DNS rewrite or how to get this to work

I have it working for a straight inside/outside interface, but on this guest network I'm stumped!

Please Help!

Thanks

P.S.  I've been through this article a dozen times but it doesnt talk about a 3rd interface:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/71704-dns-doctoring-2zones.html

Comment: Can you clarify which interface the webserver is off of?  You say that it is both on the outside 1.2.3.4 and DMZ 10.10.10.x networks.  Also, what version of software are you running?

Answer (score 0):

This quick and dirty way...

Enable a DNS inspection map. The default is fine.
I don't even pretend to know the real commands for this, so I still use the old-school Pix command:

```
fixup protocol dns
```

That will get converted to the right ASA commands.

Then you need to add the DNS translation rule to your static NAT entries, e.g.:

nat (inside,outside) static 54.20.223.182 dns

That's all. You can also add them through the Cisco ASDM by checking ["Translate DNS replies that match this rule"](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/72273-dns-doctoring-3zones5.gif) for the relevant entries.

Or you can avoid this and use internal DNS... I only do DNS doctoring when I'm desperate.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I've tried that.  In ASDM it's the DNS Rewrite check box.  But that didn't work for me.  I have a feeling one of my static rules is incorrect or missing but I can't figure out which one and which interface!  Arggg!

Comment: Did you "fixup protocol dns 53"?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't like '53'.

Comment: @AJToww Leave the "53" off.

Comment: I added that.  My static rules are in there already and I have the dns suffix on the line, but still no love.

Comment: Use the packet-tracer utility (either ssh or ASDM) to determine the affect of your existing NAT rules.  Also, what version of software are you running?